# How to get C# style triple slash comments with ReSharper++

Tags: resharper, documentation

I thought getting ReSharper would work for XML comments exactly the way it does in C#, but it doesnt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to get it to be really close to what C# does edit the `doc` Live Template.

Steps:
 1. Go to ReSharper > Tools > Templates Explorer....
 2. Select C++
 3. Select `doc` live template, and select edit

Enter this and make tweaks as needed

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="$TNAME$">$TDESCRIPTION$</param>
/// <param name="$PNAME$">$PDESCRIPTION$</param>
/// <param name="$MNAME$">$MDESCRIPTION$</param>
/// $RETURN$<returns></returns>
```

-All DESCRIPTION variables are set to constants and blank (this is for you to fill in)

-All NAME variables are, in order, Template parameter name, function parameter name, macro parameter name.

-`$RETURN$` is a function return value

So far this is all that ive needed and will update if i find i need to add another set of variables.

Once you save this template, just put cursor in the function name and press Alt+ENTER, ENTER and the comment block will appear above your function.

If anyone knows how to get this template to appear just by typing `///` above a function like in C# PLEASE COMMENT!